# Attribute to a variable another variable of different type

Tags: c, variables, types, bit-manipulation

Is this operation valid everytime ?

```
unsigned long long p64 = 0;
short int x = 7;

p64 = x;
```

So, for this example, the p64 variable will always be this one ?

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0111
```

which means

```
(p64 == 7)
```

I ask this question, because sometimes the bits after 0111 gets to be all 1, instead of 0. But the gcc compiler shows no warnings, so is this operation valid everytime? Do you have any solutions to convert 16 bits variables into 64 bits variables ?

Comment: It could also be `0000 0111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000` assuming little endian byte ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When assigning to any *unsigned* type

> .. the new type is unsigned, the value<sup>1</sup> is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.  C17dr § 6.3.1.3 3

This means `unsigned long long p64 = any_integer_type` is well defined.

With `short`, which is *signed*, positive values will convert with no value change.  Negatives will act like `p64 = neg_short + ULLONG_MAX + 1`.

As a side effect, this looks like a bit-sign extention for common `short` (2's complement - unpadded).

Detail: note that the conversion is not define in terms of bits.

---

<sup>1</sup> with integer type .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is valid. p64 will always have the value 7.

You should note that if `x`'s value is *negative* it will be sign-extended. The value -16 for example (in binary: 1111 1111 1111 0000) will be converted to a 64-bit -16 (1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0000) even though `p64` is unsigned. You could avoid this by making `x` unsigned.

Comment: Ok, so p64 = x is a good way to convert 16 bits variables(like short int) into 64 bits variables(like unsigned long long) ?